# How to handle large ASP.NET listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, viewstate

I have a `ListView` with 100 rows.

Each row represents a customer and has multiple buttons.

For example button for opening a panel with personal dates, button that open a panel with client orders.......

Let's assume that we have about 10 buttons per row. Each button with his panel.
Now, please advise me how can I handle this situation.

1. Each row with his panels.

   ```
   protected void lst_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
       switch (e.CommandName)
       {
           case "commandname":
           {   
               Panel pnl_= (Panel)lst_adverts.Items[e.Item.DataItemIndex].FindControl("idpanel");
               pnl_= false; 
               break;
           }    
       }
   }
   ```
2. One single panel for all rows

   ```
   protected void lst_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
       switch (e.CommandName)
       {
           case "commandname":
           {
               pnl_.Visible = false; 
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

I'm asking that because I am trying to reduce the size of the page.

Which is the better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly having one panel versus 100 panels in your page markup is going to be a smaller page.

As long as you do not want to have the ability to show more than one panel at a time, which I believe is the case, then go with Option #2 - a single panel for all rows.

You may want to investigate using a modal popup instead of a panel, such as [jQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [ASP.NET AJAX ModalPopupExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your advice! I will definitely study about modal popup.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask a dumb question about this 100 panels. All this panels have Visible='false'. Only on button click one panel will have Visible='true'. So an element with attribute Visible='false' can affect the page size?

Comment: @Otix - at run-time, yes if you make 99 of the panels invisible and only one visible, then the size of the rendered HTML will not be any larger than using a single panel in a modal popup. But from a development standpoint, your designer markup is going to be considerably larger because of all these panels that will need to be hidden before the HTML is rendered to the browser. So if output size is all that matters in this case, then 100 panels with 99 of them hidden at run-time, then it will not be a difference. But from a maintenance standpoint, it will be harder to maintain 100 panels vs. 1.

Comment: The problem is that if my listview has 100 rows I have a delay(about 2 sec) before any postback. This is the reason why I want to decrease the size of page.